# Binding web address to localhost

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, hosts, netsh, hosts-file

I'm trying to implement a card payment provider to my web shop, but it only accepts a real URLs as success, error and cancel callbacks. For example, the success callback should be *https://www.mywebshop.com/Checkout/PaymentSuccessful*

As I want to test the mentioned functionality locally, I need to set the payment success callback to *https://localhost:44328/Checkout/PaymentSuccessful*, but the card payment provider don't accept it (it redirects to error callback instantly).

So, I guess I should add following rows to my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 mywebshop.com
127.0.0.1 www.mywebshop.com
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work - the local app is running but when I request mywebshop.com, I got  messages below (I also tried with https/http/www)

> This site can’t be reached

> mywebshop.com refused to connect.

When I add a port, like *https://mywebshop.com:44328/*, I got error:

> Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

> HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.

If I add following binding to my applicationhost.config, nothing changes.

```
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44328:mywebshop.com" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44328:www.mywebshop.com" />
```

I also tried adding URL reservations with netsh, but it was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ngrok for your testing. Ngrok exposes local servers behind NATs and firewalls to the public internet over secure tunnels. Please check how it works page [here](https://ngrok.com/product) and its documentation [here](https://ngrok.com/docs). Their free plan is sufficient for testing.

So download ngrok and run the `ngrok.exe`. Run below command which will give you public url - something like http://4a950b92.ngrok.io/ which will point to your local site. Hopefully that will solve your problem.

```
ngrok http -host-header=localhost 8080
```